# OAuth ASP.net Client - How to Manage Current User, Access Token, and Session Timing Out?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I'm able to authenticate (implicit grant) from my client application. I receive an `access_token`. Now, I know that my client can now call a protected API.

The ASP.net client will primarily make AJAX calls (using the `access_token`) for any CRUD operation. This client will have multiple pages, though, so we will need to maintain logged in state across any postbacks and navigating away/return.

It seems like the client will have to store the access token in Session to maintain logged in state it across postbacks. So, let's say I do store the `access_token` in session, and then make it available to JS (so that it can make AJAX calls).

If the user never navigates away from the page, we could run into `access_token` expiration, and I don't want to have the user log in again. Yes, I can probably request another token in JS (with my older refresh token), but then the new `access_token` is not saved to Session.

If the user navigates away, and by the time they return, Session["access_token"] could time out - what do I do then? This can happen frequently and I don't want them to have to log back in every time.

So, it looks like a messy solution to get this straight - when either the Session times out or the `access_token` expires, I don't want them to have to be redirected to log in again. If the user wants to log out, they should either do so explicitly (clicking on a log out link) or closing the browser.

Any tips, [code] solutions, lesser-known technology, anything for this?

Comment: Thanks for articulating the question very clearly. I am also looking for solutions to these tasks on a side-project I am working on.